# Computing rational canonical form

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

I am given that $T:V\rightarrow V$ is a linear transformation over $Q$-vector space $V$. Its characteristic polynomial is $(x^2 - 2)^5(x^2+x+1)^3$ and minimal polynomial is $(x^2 - 2)^3(x^2+x+1)$. I am also given that the nullspace of $T^2-2$ is $4$-dimensional. How do I go about computing the rational canonical form for $T$?

Comment: Where does this question come from? Have you found any resources that say how to find rational canonical form from the factored characteristic polynomial?